# Form not saving to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have been trying to get a form to submit to the database but every time I submit it only saves an id.

Below is my code in my app.js file for the post route the form submits to.

```
    // CREATE add new startup to database 
app.post("/startup-submit", function(req, res) {
   // Get data from form
   var startupname = req.body.startupname;
   var url = req.body.url;
   var shortdescription = req.body.shortdescription;
   var longdescription = req.body.longdescription;
   var techstack = req.body.techstack;
   var foundeddate = req.body.foundeddate;
   var blog = req.body.blog;
   var twitter = req.body.twitter;
   var facebook = req.body.facebook;
   var linkedin = req.body.linkedin;
   var email = req.body.email;
   var foundername = req.body.foundername;
   var foundersocialmedia = req.body.foundersocialmedia;

   //Pass data through to page
   var newStartup = {
       startupname:startupname, 
       url: url, 
       shortdescription: shortdescription, 
       longdescription: longdescription, 
       techstack: techstack, 
       foundeddate: foundeddate, 
       blog: blog, 
       twitter: twitter, 
       facebook: facebook,
       linkedin: linkedin,
       email: email,
       foundername: foundername,
       foundersocialmedia: foundersocialmedia
   };
   Startup.create(newStartup, function(err, newlyCreatedStartup){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           // Redirect back to show all page
           res.redirect("/startups");
       }
        console.log(newlyCreatedStartup);
   });

});
```

My model I am using is:

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var startupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    about_startup: {
        startup_name: String,
    url: String,
    short_description: String,
    long_description: String,
    tech_stack: String,
    date_founded: Date
    },
    social_media: {
        blog: String,
        twitter: String,
        facebook: String,
        linkedin: String,
        email: String,
    },
    about_founder: {
        name: String,
        social_media_founder: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Startup", startupSchema);
```

These should line up correctly, or am I off base on this? I am new to node and express so learning has been interesting. As for how I decided on the model and layout of the code, it is mostly from a previous project I did as part of a course. I wrote the above code out but referenced I guess is the best way of saying it to the old code.

I know the variables are all pulling the data because I console.log(variableName) each one to test it out. The model looks right to me but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: `newStartup` needs to have the same structure and property names as defined in `startupSchema`. They're currently very different.

Comment: Oh.. didn't even realize that. Damm I feel dumb now. Is this correct for how to have the route?

`var about_founder = {
        foundername: req.body.foundername,
        foundersocialmedia: req.body.foundersocialmedia
   };`

Form data above, pass to page below

`var newStartup = {about_startup: about_startup, social_media: social_media, about_founder: about_founder};
   Startup.create(newStartup, function(err, newlyCreatedStartup){`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same **variable** name which you used in **model**. Your code should be like this. This code will perfectly suits you.

```
var newStartup = { about_startup: {}, social_media: {}, about_founder: {}};
newStartup.about_startup.startup_name = req.body.startupname;
newStartup.about_startup.url = req.body.url;
newStartup.about_startup.short_description = req.body.shortdescription;
newStartup.about_startup.long_description = req.body.longdescription;
newStartup.about_startup.tech_stack = req.body.techstack;
newStartup.about_startup.date_founded = req.body.foundeddate;
newStartup.social_media.blog = req.body.blog;
newStartup.social_media.twitter = req.body.twitter;
newStartup.social_media.facebook = req.body.facebook;
newStartup.social_media.linkedin = req.body.linkedin;
newStartup.social_media.email = req.body.email;
newStartup.about_founder.name = req.body.foundername;
newStartup.about_founder.social_media_founder = req.body.foundersocialmedia;

Startup.create(newStartup, function (err, newlyCreatedStartup) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // Redirect back to show all page
        res.redirect("/startups");
    }
    console.log(newlyCreatedStartup);
});
```